# Shipping methods are not listed in paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I set up some shipping costs / methods for my sandbox test account but they are not shown on the payment page. Does the sandbox support custom shipping costs / methods or am I doing something wrong?

I set up international shipping methods for Germany.

Best
krebbl

Comment: I have had issues where sandbox wasn't the same as production.  You may want to write an email to paypal to find out if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the shipping options set up on your test sandbox seller account, they should be showing on the payment pages after the buyer either enters in their credit card information and continues to the next page or after they sign in with their PayPal account.  If you still do not see these appear, can you provide a link to your checkout and I can take a look at it and see what the issue may be.

Comment: the email address of the test checkout is krebbl-facilitator@gmail.com. Is this enough?

Comment: I checked your account, and the shipping options are set up correctly.  However I do see why your shipping options are not being applied.  The shipping options are only applied to Website Payments Standard.  You are using Express Checkout.  With Express Checkout and Website Payments Pro, you have to pass over the tax and shipping costs.  These do not get calculated from your profile for EC and Pro.

Comment: I looked for other PayPal checkouts and found out that redbubble.com is also using PayPal Express Checkout and there it is possible to choose the shipping type on the PayPal page. So how do I get this behavior?

Comment: These have to be passed over, it wont allow you to use the shipping profile you set up in your account.  You can pass multiple shipping options over in your request so that the buyer can choose which option they want, but they have to be passed over in your API call.  Express Checkout will not use the shipping profile set up in your account.